# Is there an equivalent for Oracle REGEXP_REPLACE Word Boundary that acts like \b word boundary?

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm trying to replace words using Oracle's regexp_replace, and I need something that acts like the zero-length `\b` word boundary.  For some reason Oracle chose not to implement this.  If I use `\W` I can find words no problem, but when I go to replace them I also replace the word boundary found by `\W`.  For example:

```
SELECT regexp_replace('DOES JULIE WORK .JULIE. HERE','\Wjulie\W', 'James', 1, 0, 'i') regex FROM dual;
```

returns this string:

```
DOESJamesWORK James HERE
```

I want it to return:

```
DOES James WORK .James. HERE
```

Comment: Figured it out.  This works:

SELECT regexp_replace('DOES JULIE WORK .JULIE. HERE','(\W)julie(\W)', '\1James\2', 1, 0, 'i') regex FROM dual;

Learning something new about regular expressions every day!

Answer (score 1):

The regex match pattern in your comment does not work if JULIE appears at the very beginning or end of your string.  Try this instead to include the very beginning and end of the line:

```
'(^|\W)julie(\W|$)'
```

Explanation:

^ = anchor for start of the line

| = OR

$ = anchor for the end of the line